# Is there a tilt shift lens for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, tilt-shift

I am looking for a tilt shift lens for the iPhone, are there any options out there in the market?  I know there are plenty of apps that achieve the effect with software, but I am looking for an optical solution.

Answer (score 3):

You won't find actual tilt-shift lenses that does what you're looking for.

Plane of focus control (tilt, which gives you the "miniature" effect with reverse tilt) operates according to the [Scheimpflug principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheimpflug_principle). This is achieved by physically tilting the focusing lens in an optical system.

In the case of a smartphone attachment, the actual focusing lens is already permanently fixed in the phone. There are *some* effects that can be achieved by what is in essence a magnifying glass placed in front of the phone's camera lens, but I'd call those effects more "creative focus and distortion" effects than perspective control *à la* actual tilt-shift lenses.

Lensbaby makes the [LM-10 Sweet Spot Lens](http://lensbaby.com/product/lm-10/) for mobile phones. But it's not a tilt-shift — it doesn't allow you to control its focus effect, which is just center focus with more distortion and blur towards the edges.

[image: Lensbaby LM-10]
<sup>*Lensbaby LM-10 Sweet Spot Lens*, from lensbaby.com</sup>

Comment: that makes perfect sense, I forgot the lens is fixed.. whoops.